# When should I use LongRunning Task Creation option?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, task-parallel-library

I have an Azure Worker Role that has three types of processes:

- C# thread that reads from the database and writes to *worker-input-queue* (Task1)
- Java thread that reads from *worker-input-queue* does work and writes to *worker-output-queue*
- C# thread that reads from *worker-output-queue* and writes to database (Task2)

Task1 and Task2 run indefinitely and sleep if their respective queues are empty.

My code looks like this:

```
SpawnJavaProcesses();  
Task.Factory.StartNew(Task1);  
Task.Factory.StartNew(Task2);  
while(true)  
{  
    //do some trivial sporadic work  
    Thread.Sleep(60*1000);  
}
```

My questions:

- Should I use the LongRunning task creation option when starting Task1 and Task2?
- Is there a better way to implement what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: While this works on my local multi-core machine, I found that when uploading to a single-core Azure role, only the main thread and the Java processes get execution time while Task1 and Task2 don't. Does this pertain to the usage of tasks on single core systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a few threads that are long running it would be best to use the LongRunning option. By choosing this option you'll be running in a thread outside of the thread pool. This is also something which was [explained by Stephen Toub](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/8304b44f-0480-488c-93a4-ec419327183b) (from the Parallel Extensions team):

> It's not a specific length per se.  If you're generating a lot of
>   tasks, LongRunning is not appropriate for them.  If you're generating
>   one or two tasks that will persist for quite some time relative to the
>   lifetime of your application, then LongRunning is something to
>   consider.